# Earth connection on this single phase AC motor

Tags: induction-motor, grounding

I bought a drill press recently that comes equipped with a 0.5HP single phase AC motor. I have wired it up as per the instructions that came pasted on the motor but I do not see a terminal for earth on it. Do I simply connect the earth wire to one of the screws that hold the motor frame?

This is what the instruction label looks like:

[image: Wiring instructions]

This is what the wiring terminals look like:

[image: Terminals 1]

I wanted to read a little better what's under the A terminal and I temporarily disconnected those leads:

[image: A terminal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Motor earth terminal.*

Comment: Yes, no other purpose for that screw...

Comment: It seems so. In the US, typically ground screws are tinted green. Also, the female threads and area under the head of the screw would typically not have paint on them to help insure good electrical contact with the safety ground conductor.

Comment: In general (there's exceptions), if there's a ground wire in your electrical system, then the frame of your machine should be grounded.  Some countries have safety systems that involve not grounding the power wires.  Just sayin'.  See your local electrical code.